# How to do dependency injection python-way?

Tags: python, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I've been reading a lot about python-way lately so my question is

> How to do dependency injection python-way?

I am talking about usual scenarios when, for example, service A needs access to UserService for authorization checks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It all depends on the situation. For example, if you use dependency injection for testing purposes -- so you can easily mock out something -- you can often forgo injection altogether: you can instead mock out the module or class you would otherwise inject:

```
subprocess.Popen = some_mock_Popen
result = subprocess.call(...)
assert some_mock_popen.result == result
```

`subprocess.call()` will call `subprocess.Popen()`, and we can mock it out without having to inject the dependency in a special way. We can just replace `subprocess.Popen` directly. (This is just an example; in real life you would do this in a much more robust way.)

If you use dependency injection for more complex situations, or when mocking whole modules or classes isn't appropriate (because, for example, you want to only mock out one particular call) then using class attributes or module globals for the dependencies is the usual choice. For example, considering a `my_subprocess.py`:

```
from subprocess import Popen

def my_call(...):
    return Popen(...).communicate()
```

You can easily replace only the `Popen` call made by `my_call()` by assigning to `my_subprocess.Popen`; it wouldn't affect any other calls to `subprocess.Popen` (but it would replace all calls to `my_subprocess.Popen`, of course.) Similarly, class attributes:

```
class MyClass(object):
    Popen = staticmethod(subprocess.Popen)
    def call(self):
        return self.Popen(...).communicate(...)
```

When using class attributes like this, which is rarely necessary considering the options, you should take care to use `staticmethod`. If you don't, and the object you're inserting is a normal function object or another type of descriptor, like a property, that does something special when retrieved from a class or instance, it would do the wrong thing. Worse, if you used something that *right now* isn't a descriptor (like the `subprocess.Popen` class, in the example) it would work now, but if the object in question changed to a normal function future, it would break confusingly.

Lastly, there's just plain callbacks; if you just want to tie a particular instance of a class to a particular service, you can just pass the service (or one or more of the service's methods) to the class initializer, and have it use that:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, authenticate=None, authorize=None):
        if authenticate is None:
            authenticate = default_authenticate
        if authorize is None:
            authorize = default_authorize
        self.authenticate = authenticate
        self.authorize = authorize
    def request(self, user, password, action):
        self.authenticate(user, password)
        self.authorize(user, action)
        self._do_request(action)

...
helper = AuthService(...)
# Pass bound methods to helper.authenticate and helper.authorize to MyClass.
inst = MyClass(authenticate=helper.authenticate, authorize=helper.authorize)
inst.request(...)
```

When setting instance attributes like that, you never have to worry about descriptors firing, so just assigning the functions (or classes or other callables or instances) is fine.

Comment: I have C# background so I am used to explicit injections via constructor and using Container to resolve everything. Specifying defaults to None in initializer looks like "poor man's DI" which doesn't look like the best practice to me as it's not explicit enough. Similar thoughts about replacing existing methods by assignment (is this what is called `monkey patching`?). Should I just change my mindset because python-way differs from C#-way?

Comment: Yes, if you want to write efficient, pythonic code, you should realize that Python is quite a different language. You do different things differently. Monkeypatching modules for testing is really very common and quite safe (especially when using a proper mocking library to handle the details for you.) Monkeypatching classes (changing specific methods on classes) is a different matter.

The None defaults are really not the thing you should focus on -- that example is actually quite close to DI through the constructor, you can just omit the default and make it a required argument if you  want.

Comment: @ThomasWouters can you explain this: 
_You can easily replace only the Popen call made by my_call() by assigning to my_subprocess.Popen._
Do you mean `subprocess.call` invokes a call to `subprocess.Popen`?

Answer (score 2):

After years using Python without any DI autowiring framework and Java with Spring I've come to realize plain simple Python code often doesn't need frameworks for dependency injection without autowiring (autowiring is what Guice and Spring both do in Java), i.e., just doing something like this is enough:

```py
def foo(dep = None):  # great for unit testing!
    self.dep = dep or Dep()  # callers can not care about this too
    ...
```

This is pure dependency injection (quite simple) but without magical frameworks for automatically injecting them for you (i.e., autowiring) and without Inversion of Control.

Though as I dealt with bigger applications this approach wasn't cutting it anymore. So I've come up with [injectable](https://github.com/allrod5/injectable) a micro-framework that wouldn't feel non-pythonic and yet would provide first class dependency injection autowiring.

Under the motto *Dependency Injection for Humans™* this is what it looks like:

```py
# some_service.py
class SomeService:
    @autowired
    def __init__(
        self,
        database: Autowired(Database),
        message_brokers: Autowired(List[Broker]),
    ):
        pending = database.retrieve_pending_messages()
        for broker in message_brokers:
            broker.send_pending(pending)
```

```py
# database.py
@injectable
class Database:
    ...
```

```py
# message_broker.py
class MessageBroker(ABC):
    def send_pending(messages):
        ...
```

```py
# kafka_producer.py
@injectable
class KafkaProducer(MessageBroker):
    ...
```

```py
# sqs_producer.py
@injectable
class SQSProducer(MessageBroker):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

#### What is dependency injection?

Dependency injection is a principle that helps to decrease coupling and increase cohesion.

Coupling and cohesion are about how tough the components are tied.

- **High coupling**. If the coupling is high it’s like using a superglue or welding. No easy way to disassemble.
- **High cohesion**. High cohesion is like using the screws. Very easy to disassemble and assemble back or assemble a different way. It is an opposite to high coupling.

When the cohesion is high the coupling is low.

Low coupling brings a flexibility. Your code becomes easier to change and test.

#### How to implement the dependency injection?

Objects do not create each other anymore. They provide a way to inject the dependencies instead.

before:

```py
import os


class ApiClient:

    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = os.getenv('API_KEY')  # <-- dependency
        self.timeout = os.getenv('TIMEOUT')  # <-- dependency


class Service:

    def __init__(self):
        self.api_client = ApiClient()  # <-- dependency


def main() -> None:
    service = Service()  # <-- dependency
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

after:

```py
import os


class ApiClient:

    def __init__(self, api_key: str, timeout: int):
        self.api_key = api_key  # <-- dependency is injected
        self.timeout = timeout  # <-- dependency is injected


class Service:

    def __init__(self, api_client: ApiClient):
        self.api_client = api_client  # <-- dependency is injected


def main(service: Service):  # <-- dependency is injected
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(
        service=Service(
            api_client=ApiClient(
                api_key=os.getenv('API_KEY'),
                timeout=os.getenv('TIMEOUT'),
            ),
        ),
    )
```

`ApiClient` is decoupled from knowing where the options come from. You can read a key and a timeout from a configuration file or even get them from a database.

`Service` is decoupled from the `ApiClient`. It does not create it anymore. You can provide a stub or other compatible object.

Function `main()` is decoupled from `Service`. It receives it as an argument.

Flexibility comes with a price.

Now you need to assemble and inject the objects like this:

```py
main(
    service=Service(
        api_client=ApiClient(
            api_key=os.getenv('API_KEY'),
            timeout=os.getenv('TIMEOUT'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

The assembly code might get duplicated and it’ll become harder to change the application structure.

#### Conclusion

Dependency injection brings you 3 advantages:

- **Flexibility**. The components are loosely coupled. You can easily extend or change a functionality of the system by combining the components different way. You even can do it on the fly.
- **Testability**. Testing is easy because you can easily inject mocks instead of real objects that use API or database, etc.
- **Clearness and maintainability**. Dependency injection helps you reveal the dependencies. Implicit becomes explicit. And “Explicit is better than implicit” (PEP 20 - The Zen of Python). You have all the components and dependencies defined explicitly in the container. This provides an overview and control on the application structure. It is easy to understand and change it.

—-

I believe that through the already presented example you will understand the idea and be able to apply it to your problem, ie the implementation of *UserService for authorization*.

Comment: This is a FastAPI + SQLAlchemy + Dependency Injector [example application](https://github.com/ets-labs/python-dependency-injector/tree/master/examples/miniapps/fastapi-sqlalchemy).  Maybe it's helpful for yours _UserService for authorization_.

Answer (score 1):

How about this  "setter-only" injection recipe?
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413268/

It is quite pythonic, using the "descriptor" protocol with `__get__()`/`__set__()`, but rather invasive, requiring to replace all your attribute-setting code with a `RequiredFeature` instance initialized with the str-name of the `Feature` required.

Answer (score 0):

I recently released a DI framework for python that might help you here. I think its a fairly fresh take on it, but I'm not sure how 'pythonic' it is. Judge for yourself. Feedback is very welcome.

https://github.com/suned/serum